# How to get the list of computers a user can RDP into using BloodHound?

Tags: active-directory, rdp, enumeration

Using bloodhound I would like to find the list of all computers a user I.e "domain\ajohn" can RDP into.

I looked at:

```
match p=(g:Group)-[:CanRDP]->(c:Computer) where g.objectid ENDS WITH '-513'  AND NOT c.operatingsystem CONTAINS 'Server' return p
```

This does not return any results for me

I don't know how to define the user name on this query so I get any type of computer where "domain\ajohn" can RDP into.

Can someone help?